# How to make it look like a table with CSS?

Tags: css

Hello i got this code on my WordPress description that was inserted while uploading CSV file.

Now that text is not so nice too look at, i want to make it as a table but this code is not included with HTML table code.

Now i got this:

```
<dt class="xsc">Weight:</dt>

<dd class="datalist__value datalist__value--horizontal"><span class="datalist__value__inner">82g</span></dd>
```

This shows Weight:
               82g

How can i make it look like this with css? 
[image]

Who will help me get 1billion karma points! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this can help you with only css, you just have to add one div

```css
.fake-table {
    width: 200px;
}

.fake-table dt, .fake-table dd {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 2%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;

    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fake-table:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.fake-table dt:hover, .fake-table dd:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="fake-table">

  <dt class="xsc">Weight:</dt>

  <dd class="datalist__value datalist__value--horizontal">
<span class="datalist__value__inner">82g</span>
 </dd>
 
 <dt class="xsc">jfkldsf fjdklf fjdsklf fjdkslf fjdksl</dt>

  <dd class="datalist__value datalist__value--horizontal">
<span class="datalist__value__inner">82g</span>
 </dd>
 
 <dt class="xsc">Weight:</dt>

  <dd class="datalist__value datalist__value--horizontal">
<span class="datalist__value__inner">82g</span>
 </dd>

</div>
```

Comment: Rahul, your solution removed my headache instantly. Great great guy ;)

Comment: Now i got this white spot somewhere : https://www.imgpost.co.uk/images/2018/12/06/fsf.png how can i make it fullwidht?

Comment: see updated changes, this is max can be done with just css

Comment: Thank you! Rahul

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table`. Documentation is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) is a more detailed doc.

```
<div style="display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      Gross but sometimes useful.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you do not need to use `table` html tags.